# turning igraph adjacency matrix into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, igraph

By writing

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph()
g.add_vertices(6)
g.add_edges([(0,1),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(1,2),(2,4),(2,5),(3,0),(3,2),(3,5),(4,5),(3,3)])
A=g.get_adjacency()
```

I get the adjacency matrix of graph g, as a Matrix object. I want to calculate its eigenvalues by using, for example, `numpy.linalg.eigvals()`. This method takes a numpy array object as argument.
How do I convert a Matrix object into a numpy array object?
I tried by using

```
X=numpy.matrix(A)
```

but it produced some mixture of the two and eigenvalues could not be calculated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the documentation of iGraph's matrix class](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.datatypes.Matrix-class.html), you could retrieve the data as a list of lists and then convert easily to a numpy ndarray:

```
A = g.get_adjacency()
A = np.array(A.data)
```

Comment: @Joel, you're not reading it fully. The interface is there: it is provided by the property `data` of the igraph `Matrix`class. Once you have it as a list of lists, you can convert it to a numpy array. The code above works, but converting to a numpy array is obviously not mentioned in the docs (to allow interfaces to any library). The solution above is what I came up with after reading (and testing). What you link to that doesn't work is trying to convert an instance of igraph's `Matrix` class to a numpy array *directly*, which will fail (it 'll return an array with dtype object).

Comment: gotcha - skimmed right past the `A.data` in your snippet.

Comment: Works great, thanks! I hope it will appear some day in the documentation of igraph…

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you're after, but here's how to do it with networkx (option with igraph is below - I think):

```
import networkx as nx
G= nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(1,2),(2,4),(2,5),(3,0),(3,2),(3,5),(4,5),(3,3)])
A=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)  #by default A is sparse

import numpy as np
np.linalg.eig(A.todense())
```

I don't have igraph, so not sure if a similar .todense() might work for the Matrix type it returns.

**edit** I see some suggestion that

```
numpy.array(list(g.get_adjacency()))
```

might do what you're after with igraph.  I don't have igraph, so can't test.  Please let me know if it works.  (but consider networkx anyways ;) )

**re-edit** I think the solution by Oliver is cleaner.  But I still want to leave the networkx version and this other igraph approach for others to see.